# Build Maven Scala Project with Akka

Tags: scala, maven, akka

Usually, I am using SBT to build Scala Projects.
Lately, I have been asked to integer an existing project, they use Maven as development tool.
I wanna work with Maven to build an Akka-Scala Project. I couldn't find any tool to build that.

I tried to make a new Maven project from Eclips (New Project ==> Maven Project), then Add actor library (Proprieties => Build Path => Add Akka Library from external Libraries). But it didn't work.

Can you recommend any IDE/Tool to do that ?

Comment: What have out tried? Have you created a new "vanilla" Maven project, or used a Scala archetype? Please include your POM in the question, as it stands now, there's insufficient information to diagnose and solve your problem.

Comment: I didn't use non of these ? I just created a new project SBT as I usually do.

Comment: I've you used "New Project => Maven Project", there should be a POM.xml file in the created project's root.

Comment: Yes. It is ? what about these projects mentioned above "vanilla" Maven project, or used a Scala archetype?

Answer (score 0):

You will need scala-maven-plugging at least for maven to know about Scala. Scala archetype looks like good solution, but I haven't used it. This also may help http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/m2eclipse/index.html